# MOSFET transistor switching from saturation mode to linear mode

Tags: transistors, mosfet

[image]

With the MOSFET transistor M<sub>1</sub> where:

W/L = 2,
V<sub>DD</sub> = 4.5 V,
µ<sub>n</sub>C<sub>ox</sub> = 100 µA/V²,
and threshold voltage V<sub>th</sub> = 0.65 V.

What is the voltage V<sub>1</sub> at which M<sub>1</sub> switches from saturation mode to linear mode?

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-002-circuits-and-electronics-spring-2007/5d9288b54aceb1737d8f831d3c66739b_6002_l9.pdf (page 20
)

Comment: For homework type questions you need to show some effort in calculating this yourself and demonstrate that by adding your calculations to the question. Only then will somebody be able to guide you in overcoming your barriers.